# How to inspect the fs of a running Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-run

Is there a way to inspect a running Docker container? E.g., inspect the filesystem using a shell, etc?

To inspect an image, we could using `docker run <tag> /bin/bash` but I am looking to inspect a running container, not an image.

note that `docker container inspect` is not what I am looking for - that command just gives me metadata about the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your container has a typical filesystem, you can just use `docker exec` to start a shell inside the container, as in:

```
docker exec -it mycontainer bash
```

Or if `bash` isn't available (for example, Alpine-based images):

```
docker exec -it mycontainer sh
```

Alternatively, you can export a container's filesystem as a `tar` archive using `docker export`.  For example:

```
docker export -o mycontainer.tar mycontainer
```

And then you can inspect the archive or extract it as necessary.  If
you just want to a file listing, then:

```
docker export mycontainer | tar tf -
```

Comment: `docker export` does not export the contents of volumes associated with the container - which I suspect will be some of the most interesting files to the OP.

Comment: That's true.  If you need to see the contents of volumes, either stick with the `docker exec` variations, or mount the volumes into another container (using for example the `--volumes-from` option).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command

```
docker exec -it {container Id or name} command
```